# User Profile Page - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have an issue that I made a php code and I made a registration system, now, I have successfully made a user page which is like ( ?id=1 )

But if I view ?id=2 it still shows data for user id=1 (me)
How can i solve that?

And how can i hide the Edit profile button for userid2 if I am not userid2 ?

PHP:

```html
<?

session_start();
include 'db.php';
$iDD = $_SESSION['id'];

?>

<a href="home.php?id=<?php echo $iDD;?>">edit user Login</a><br><br>

<?php

$DOO = $_GET['id'];
$SEL= $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=:id");
$SEL->execute(array(
'id' => $iDD
));
$data = $SEL->fetchall();
foreach ($data as $row){
echo "your username:".$row['user']."<br>";
echo "your user password:".$row['pass']."<br>";
echo "your user id:".$row['id']."<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: You are saving the GET parameter in $DOO but that variable is never used. Or am i missing something?

Comment: No, $DOO is used to $_GET['id']

You aren't missing anything.

Comment: So how do you expect to get userdata depending on your get parameter if you aren't using $DOO anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if statement like this:

```
<?php if ($iDD == 1): ?>
    <a href="home.php?id=<?php echo $iDD;?>">edit user Login</a><br><br>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change as follows;

```
$SEL->execute(array(
 'id' => $DOO
));
```